# How to show current time updating in recycler view in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-recyclerview

Say I want to show current time for each cell in recycler view in format (mm:ss). This time updates every second, and the recycler view cells should reflect that. If the user scrolls down to the bottom of the list, a new item should be added to recycler view and that cell should start counting up from zero. How would I achieve this type of design?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a trigger when the list ends, create a new item put the time in there and start counting up using a handler.

However this method would fail in the long run, recycle view as it's name suggests uses "old" items and their references to accumulate for new items. The ID's of old items would be confused with new items and the list would start to mess up.

source: https://android.jlelse.eu/understanding-recyclerview-a-high-level-insight-part-1-dc3f81af5720